In windows 10 dark mode, windows file explorer's status bar stays white
In Windows 10 dark mode, Windows file explorer's status bar stays white, the font however switches to white from black, so it becomes close to invisible. Check the link below for screenshot.
Windows File Explorer Status Bar White in Dark mode
I had tried Uxthemepatcher in the past when dark mode was not there
After uninstall, I executed -sfc/scannow, which repaired the DLLs:

2024-07-26 12:23:55, Info                  CSI    00000139 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013a Hashes for file member [l:11]'themeui.dll' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:413d9bfadabc09fccb2bdfc99ca4369b87520755b609254905331f8fbeeb06cc}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:b39636aa5734009fa7d707e8ab4de587be21b7c77096509e8e6fb98c055b1b41}.
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013b [SR] Repairing file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\\themeui.dll from store
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013c [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013d [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    0000013f [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    00000140 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    00000141 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000142 CSIPERF - FilePI Queue 292ms
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000143 Hashes for file member [l:10]'UXInit.dll' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:124cb2f9819f673f46cc976d511740f0d5bd4f1f25e45b7a4ff3d2047b709373}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:752901750c0dfc9f456111cb163731df3a8575302d2ee86753701c7ff6b16f29}.
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000144 [SR] Repairing file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\\UXInit.dll from store
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000145 [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:00, Info                  CSI    00000146 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:00, Info                  CSI    00000147 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    00000148 [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    00000149 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    0000014a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    0000014b [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014c [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014d [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014e [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014f [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    00000150 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:04, Info                  CSI    00000151 CSIPERF - FilePI Queue 185ms
2024-07-26 12:24:04, Info                  CSI    00000152 [SR] Verify complete

But still it is like this.
Tried changing themes, changing light and dark mode & restarting system multiple times
Also tried SFC, this time it shows no modified DLLs
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.


You will need to remove Uxthemepatcher and verify this bug isn’t caused by Uxthemepatcher

I removed it, it is still there.

I never asked.  Does it happen while in Safe Mode, and do you have anything else like StartIsBack or Start11 installed?  Of course, I was never able to reproduce this error, so it must be something that is installed on your system causing the problem with File Explorer.

Are there some tags I forgot to provide? It seemed to be simple issue for someone who has faced it. Or maybe I'm the only one in the whole world :P

@Ramhound, could be, though, I don't have anything other than a clock from windows store and a wallpaper changer when it comes to UI.

It’s probably a unique third-party application. So does it happen while in Safe Mode? What about a new user?

Does removing uxthemepatcher fully revert any and all changes that utility made to the system? In my several work and personal computers, Explorer has followed the system themes correctly.
